# java после nextInt проблемы с nextLine

Tags: java

Есть такой код,который должен выводить информацию о 3 книгах, но код останавливается после 2ой и ошибка(Индекс 3 выходит за пределы длины 3) если в массив добавить еще 1 обьект то код работает до 3х если в массиве 5 обьекта то код работает до 4х,почему так? но у меня должен быть максимум 3 обьекта и выводить результатов этих 3 обьектов

```
package com.company;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Book {
        private String name,author,baspager;
        private int n;
    
        public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }
    
        public void setAuthor(String author){
            this.author = author;
        }
        public String getAuthor(){
            return author;
        }
    
        public void setBaspager(String baspager){
            this.baspager = baspager;
        }
        public String getBaspager(){
            return baspager;
        }
    
        public void setN(int n){
            this.n = n;
        }
        public int getN(){
            return n;
        }
    
        public void getBookInfo(){
            System.out.println("Кітаптың аты:" + name + "Кітаптың авторы:" + author + "Кітаптың баспагері: " + baspager + "Кітаптың бет саны:" + n);
        }
    }
    
    
    class lab2Result{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            String a;
    
            Book Book1 = new Book();
            Book Book2 = new Book();
            Book Book3 = new Book();
           // Book Book4 = new Book();
    
            Book objects[] = {Book1,Book2,Book3};
    
            Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    
            for(int i = 1;i <= 4;i++) {
               /* if (i == 4) {
                    break;
                }*/
    
                objects[i].setName(x.nextLine());
                objects[i].setAuthor(x.nextLine());
                objects[i].setN(x.nextInt());
                x.nextLine();
                objects[i].setBaspager(x.nextLine());
    
    
                objects[i].getBookInfo();
    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: А нулевой элемент игнорите? Это Джава, детка))))

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець это в любом языке так

Comment: не в любом. В паскале можно объявить массив с 23-го по 85ый элемент и такими же индексами оперировать

Answer (score 1):

я понял) там массив начинается с 0 а мой цикл с 1 поэтому так